# R warning:missing value needed

Tags: r

the code writes that:

```
for (i in 1:length(BNC_TEST)) {# load current corpus file
  corpus.file_word_le <- scan(BNC_TEST[i], what="char", sep="\n")
```

then it appears:

> Error in if (file == "") file <- stdin() else { :    missing value
>   where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please copy the output from `dput(BNC_TEST)` in your question! Read [mcve]!

Comment: Probably `NA` is encountered in BNC_TEST[i], where some value is expected.